# Function from ASP to PHP

Tags: php, asp-classic

I'm trying to convert the following function from ASP to PHP:

```
  Function InvalidParam(response)
            InvalidParam = IsEmpty(response) Or response = ""
        End Function
```

I am not sure how to reference the function name inside the function in PHP as has been done in ASP.

```
public function invalidParam($response) {

}
```

Comment: Rather than asking a series of how to do [INSERT ASP THING HERE] in PHP questions, why don't you just learn the language? (The [online manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) is pretty good.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public function invalidParam($response) {  
return empty($response);
}
```

But you can just as well use the empty function by itself

The following things are considered to be empty:

> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> var $var; (a variable declared, but
>   without a value in a class)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use the inbuilt function empty in php for this.
Link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php